# Tweaking a ColorTransform object

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

The official [docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/ColorTransform.html#includeExamplesSummary) say:

> You must use the new ColorTransform()
>   constructor to create a ColorTransform
>   object before you can call the methods
>   of the ColorTransform object.

So does this mean *every* time I want to tweak the color transform, I have to create a new instance? If so, the setter properties seem pretty pointless and my tests are showing this is the case.

So if every render I want to cycle say the `redOffset` based on time (to get a pulsing effect), do I have to manually create a new `ColorTransform` passing all constructor args from `this.transform.colorTransform`:

```
var newRedOffset:Number = ...
transform.colorTransform = new ColorTransform(
 transform.colorTransform.redMultiplier, transform.colorTransform.greenMultiplier,
 transform.colorTransform.blueMultiplier, transform.colorTransform.alphaMultiplier,

 newRedOffset, transform.colorTransform.greenOffset,
 transform.colorTransform.blueOffset, transform.colorTransform.alphaOffset );
```

It seems horrible, is there a shortcut?

Answer (score 2):

rather than dealing with color multipliers and alpha offsets, here's a simple, straight forward way to change the color of a display object:

```
var ct:ColorTransform = new ColorTransform();
ct.color = 0xFF0000; //Simple Hex Color value

myDisplayObject.transform.colorTransform = ct;
```

this way you can change the color property of the same ColorTransform object and then reapply it to your display object.

Comment: that's assuming you are dealing with solid colors, of course, and not color manipulation of bitmaps.

Comment: How does this single color get treated - is it equivalent to the offset portion only?

Comment: yes.  it's a huge convenience if you don't need specific settings for the multipliers.  keep in mind that color transformations are applied to the entire display object, including any filters like drop shadow.  from the docs on the color property:  http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/ColorTransform.html#color

Answer (score 2):

No, it doesn't.  You can use the colorTransform the object already has, but you need to reassign it after you have changed the values:

```
var trans:ColorTransform = sprite.transform.colorTransform;
trans.blueOffset += 10;
sprite.transform.colorTransform = trans;
```